# Python; extract rows from csv if particular column is filled

Tags: python, csv

I've got a csv file with 5 colums. The fifth column is the one with a possible comment. Now I would like to extract only the rows of which the fifth column is filled. So from the example below only the fourth row (or fifth if header is included). Then I would like to write this row in a csv with the same format. Hope anyone can help.

```
location;datetime;WNS2186;WNS2186 quality;WNS2186 comments  
241-036-00021_polder;10-02-2017 15:40;-2.272;original reliable;  
241-036-00021_polder;10-02-2017 15:50;-2.272;original reliable;  
241-036-00021_polder;10-02-2017 16:00;-2.272;original reliable;  
241-036-00021_polder;10-02-2017 16:10;-2.272;original reliable;test comment  
241-036-00021_polder;10-02-2017 16:20;-2.272;original reliable;   
241-036-00021_polder;10-02-2017 16:30;-2.272;original reliable;
```

Comment: Open your csv file, iterate over each line and check if line has comment. Also you can use python csv module

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this as a generator function that yields back rows that meet your criteria.

```
import csv

def valid_rows(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        yield from (row for row in reader if row['comments'])
```